# How to handle rank deficiency in a generalized linear model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to understand if my model is sound even if there is rank deficiency.  I am performing a generalized linear model with a binomial (or binary) distribution. My model has the fixed effect of Lineage, which is also nested in Status (fixed factor). I have another fixed factor called Density and there is an interaction effect between Density (low, medium, and high) and Status (native or invasive). Aliveordead is my binary dependent variable (it simply means the subject was alive or dead). I decided to simplify the model by only using the interaction effects (Density*Status), which is answering the most important question.

```
mixed <- glmer(Aliveordead ~ Density:Status - (1|Lineage) - (Lineage/Status) - Density - Status, data = data, family = binomial)
summary (mixed)
```

I receive these warnings:

```
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

     ___________________________________________________________________

fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

Warning messages:
1: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
2: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

The only factor that was removed by R (because of rank deficiency) in the model was "Densitymedium:StatusNative". Is this a sound model? I dislike removing factors from the model (like Lineage)- am I removing them from the model by using "-"?

Comment: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850169/multicollinearity-test-with-carvif/71850818#71850818 ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71270248/error-warning-on-running-glm-in-r-coefficients-1-not-defined-because-of-sing/71270467#71270467 ;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337761/linear-regression-na-estimate-just-for-last-coefficient/7341074#7341074=

Comment: Thank you Ben! I realized from my formatting issues that my post excluded "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping..." This comment will help me in the future when I do have to handle multicollinearity.

Comment: Did you read those other questions/answers? Did the answers make sense? Subtracting the main effects doesn't actually do what you think ... (you can illustrate this more clearly with a simple `lm()` or `glm()`, it doesn't involve the random-effects component of the model at all).

Comment: I attempted a glm on your advice! glm(Presence ~ Density:Status - Density - Status, data = data, family = binomial) and I did received the warning:

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   -1.6818     0.3850  -4.368 1.26e-05 ***
DensityMedium:StatusNative         NA         NA      NA       NA

I will take a look at how to fix this multicollinearity effect.